# How to calculate the cubic Bézier spline points?

Tags: cubics, bezier-curve, spline

I want to draw a Bézier curve.I have four points are p0,p1,p2,p3. Draw the curve from P0 to P1, it is the start and end point of the curve. How to calculate the intermediate point to draw curve? 
I need to find the point as mentioned in the below image.

[Spline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhxdZ.png)

I get the Bézier curve derivation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves this article. I can find the new point from this derivation. I don't know how to use the point to draw curve? I need four points to draw a curve P0,p00,p01,P1, I have P0 and P1. How can I find the p00 and p01 point using from this calculation. Please suggest me?

I tried this code

```
double px0 = 0, px1 = 0, px2 = 0, px3 = 0, py0 = 0, py1 = 0, py2 = 0, py3 = 0, px4 = 0, py4 = 0;

px0 = xValues[i - 1]; 
px1 = xValues[i]; 
px2 = xValues[i + 1]; 
px3 = xValues[i + 2]; 
px4 = xValues[i + 3];

py0 = yValues[i - 1]; 
py1 = yValues[i]; 
py2 = yValues[i + 1]; 
py3 = yValues[i + 2]; 
py4 = yValues[i + 3];

PointX.Add(xValues[i]+ (Math.Pow((1 - ten), 3) * px0
            + 3 * ten * Math.Pow((1 - ten), 2) * px1 
            + 3 * ten * ten * (1 - ten) * px2 
            + ten * ten * ten * px3)/2);
PointY.Add(yValues[i]+ (Math.Pow((1 - ten), 3) * py0
            + 3 * ten * Math.Pow((1 - ten), 2) * py1
            + 3 * ten * ten * (1 - ten) * py2 
            + ten * ten * ten * py3)/2);
```

Now I can get the new point(pointX and PointY). How to draw the curve using this points?

Comment: Do you know the derivatives in the end points or anything else? If not, there is not _the correct_ solution and you can use try and error two find the missing point so that the curve matches your image. An image is not enough to rigorously derive the points.

Comment: Note that Bezier curves are normally used when you know the value and derivate in the end points, note how the example you refer to is a curve starting at $P_0$ moving *towards* $P_1$ and finaly reaches $P_3$ from the direction to $P_2$ (it does not normally pass $P_1$ and $P_2$). Your attempt to try to use Bezier curve to go through four known points is a bit odd. Note how the.

Comment: As I already said I know the start and end points.I want to find the first control point and second control point from the four points. Using the (P0,firstcontrolPoint,secondControlPoint,P1) points to draw a bezier curve.

Comment: @Santhiya I think the question is why you want to do this...

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. Can you formulate the problem more precisely?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Query 1 : Can you please explain the Cubic Bezier curve? I know only the formula, using the formula, I can get some points, But i dont know what is the use of it and how to use the points to draw the path using the Bezier Segment.

Query 3: I want the spline as like the excel Scatter with Smooth line? Could you tell me Excel spline algorithm?

Comment: Query 2: My requirement is to draw the Bezier curve using any spline algorithm.I have 10 data points, if I calculated the control points using the Cubic Bezier means, how to apply the points in the path.
data1=( X = 10, Y = 133);data2=( X = 11, Y = 80);data3=( X = 30, Y = 160);data4=( X = 42, Y =52);
polysegment = new BezierSegment();
I know the start point and Point3
pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(10, 133.505099876088);polysegment.Point3 = new Point(11, 80.1025132905238);
How to find the point1 and point2
polysegment.Point1 = ?
polysegment.Point2 = ?

Comment: And my code is IF I use the below logic means I get one point how to get the another point?
var s = i / DataCount;
var h1 = 2 * s * s * s - 3 * s * s + 1;
var h2 = -2 * s * s + 3 * s * s;
var h3 = (s * s * s) - 2 * (s * s) + s;var h4 = s * s * s - s * s;var T1 = 0.5 * (xValues[i + 1] - xValues[i]);
var T2 = 0.5 * (xValues[i + 2] - xValues[i - 1]);
Point.Add(h1 * xValues[i] + h2 * xValues[i + 1] + h3 * T1 + h4 * T2);
I am really confused to find the intermediate points

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way one normally uses Bézier curves, in fact it's quite odd way to use them.

The reason is that (cubic) Bézier curves are cubic curves to be constructed from knowing $p(0)$, $p'(0)$, $p'(1)$ and $p(1)$. The intermediate points only plays the role of indicating $p'(0)$ and $p'(1)$, it's not that the curve normally would pass through these intermediate points.

Note that the Bézier curve is basically just a cubic polynomial fulfilling the boundary conditions - and it's the only one that does it.

If you want a cubic polynomial that passes through select points you can do that as well, but the Bézier form is not very practical in doing so. Instead one would for example use [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) for that. We can for example construct a polynomial $p(t)=at^3+bt^2+ct+d$ such that $p(0)=p_0$, $p(1/3)=p_1$, $p(2/3)=p_2$ and $p(1)=p_3$.

Now if you must have it in the Bézier form you can expand the Bézier form and then matching the parameters so the polynomials match. You have:

$$p(t) = (1-t)^3q_0 + 3(1-t)^2tq_1 + 3(1-t)t^2q_2 + t^3q_3 \\
= (1-3t+3t^2-t^3)q_0 + (3t-6t^2+3t^3)q_1 + (3t^2-3t^3)q_2 + t^3q_3\\
= q_0 + (3q_1-3q_0)t + (3q_0-6q_1+3q_2)t^2 + (q_3-3q_2+3q_1-1)t^3$$

Now it's just a matter of solving for $q_j$. First we have that $q_0 = c$, then one inserts that in $3q_1-3q_0 = b$ and solve for $q_1$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear what you're asking, so this is just a guess.

What I think is ... you have four points that the Bezier curve passes through, and you want to find its control points.

So, let $\mathbf{C}$ denote the curve, let $\mathbf{Q}_0$, $\mathbf{Q}_1$, $\mathbf{Q}_2$, $\mathbf{Q}_3$ be the known points that it passes through, and let $\mathbf{P}_0$, $\mathbf{P}_1$, $\mathbf{P}_2$, $\mathbf{P}_3$ be its control points, which we want to find.

Obviously 
$\mathbf{P}_0 = \mathbf{Q}_0 = \mathbf{C}(0)$ and 
$\mathbf{P}_3 = \mathbf{Q}_3 = \mathbf{C}(1)$.

I'm going to arrange things so that $\mathbf{C}\big(\tfrac13\big) = \mathbf{Q}_1$  and $\mathbf{C}\big(\tfrac23\big) = \mathbf{Q}_2$. The $\tfrac13$ and $\tfrac23$ are arbitrary choices, just for simplicity. After solving a couple of linear equations, you get
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}_{1} & = \tfrac16\big(  -5\mathbf{Q}_0 
                                + 18\mathbf{Q}_1 
                                - 9 \mathbf{Q}_2 
                                + 2 \mathbf{Q}_3  \big)  \\
\mathbf{P}_{2} & = \tfrac16\big(  \;\;\;\;2\mathbf{Q}_0 
                               - 9 \mathbf{Q}_1 
                               + 18\mathbf{Q}_2 
                              - 5 \mathbf{Q}_3  \big)
\end{align*}